# Normal variation of embedded surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M^3$ be a complete riemannian manifold and $\Sigma ^2\subset M^3$ a embedded minimal compact surface. Consider the normal variation $\phi: \Sigma \times \Bbb{R}\to M$ given by

$$\phi(p,t)=\exp_p(tN(p)),$$

when $N$ is a normal vector field along to $\Sigma.$

I want to show that:

**Lemma:** There is $\delta>0$ such that $\phi:\Sigma\times [0,\delta) \to M$ is a embedded.

I tried a sketch with tubular neighborhood but I don't conclude anything in this direction. In fact, I know that there is the tubular neighborhood of $\Sigma$, but I don't how immerse this in $M$.

Anyone has a little help?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v$ be any tangent vector of $\Sigma$, then
$d\phi_{(p, 0)}(v, 0)=v$ since when $t=0$, $\phi(p, 0)=p$ is the projection to $\Sigma$.
And $d\phi_{(p, 0)}(0, dt)=N_p$ based on the definition of the $\exp$ map.
So if we choose a basis on $T_p\Sigma$ together with $d/dt$ for $T_p\Sigma\times T\mathbb{R}$ and the same basis together with $N$ in $T_p M$, the differential is of the form of an identity matrix. Thus it is an embedding when $t=0$.
The conclusion follows immediately since the map is smooth.

Comment: Thanks for you help @XipanXiao, but in fact I'm really confused. Can you explicite more details in the you answer? I thanks a lot.

Comment: An embedding is an injective immersion, whose differential is injective. My argument only showed that the differential is injective, we still need to show that the map is injective, but I'm a little busy for now.

Comment: Actually when $t=0$, the map is obviously injective, thus it is indeed an embedding when $t=0$.

Comment: I figured out that, thanks. Just more a think, how you calculate the $d\phi_{(p,0)}$ in this case? Because, I know calculate just the $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\phi$.

Comment: Let $v\in T_p\Sigma$, and $c$ is a curve starting from $p$ with $c'(0)=v$. $\phi(c(t), 0)=c(t)$, so the differential maps the tangent vector $(v, 0)$, to the tangent vector of the image curve, that is, $c'(0)$.

Comment: You need to use that $\Sigma$ is compact, or the statement is false.

Comment: @JohnMa, can you tell me more details? I'm really confused with it.

Comment: Since it's compact it can be covered by finite coordinate charts. In each chart $U_i$ we can show that there is $\delta_i$ such that the statement holds. Choose the minimal $\delta_i$ as $\delta$. This is a standard 'compactness argument'.

Comment: @XipanXiao You need to refine your argument as this is not true. Think of a compact surface in $\mathbb R^3$, so that a large part is formed by two parallel plane (so that $\phi|_{V_i \times \mathbb R}$ is an embedding for a small $V_i$). $U_i$ so that $\phi|_{U_i}$ is embedding, however $\phi$ itself is not. You need to show why $\delta = \min \delta_i$ would do. If I understand correct, that at least depend on the curvature.